# Completely ignore single folder using .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a couple of questions about *.gitignore*.

In my repo I have a folder `[repo root]\Sub1\Printouts` that contains some pdf files.
I want GIT to **completely** ignore everything that happens in `[repo root]\Sub1\Printouts` (new files, file deletions, file modifications), so I added this to *.gitignore*:

```
Sub1\Printouts\
```

However, if I delete a file in `Sub1\Printouts` and run `git status`, i have:

```
modified:   .gitignore
deleted:    Sub1/Printouts/aaa.pdf
```

The same happens if I add a new file, but **not** if I edit one.

I also have another question: reading on various sites I understand that an entry like `Sub1\Printouts\` should match a folder called `Printouts` that is inside a folder called `Sub1`, everywhere in the repo. That means that all the following folders should be ignored:

```
 1) [repo root]\Sub1\Printouts
 2) [repo root]\Some folder\Sub1\Printouts
 3) [repo root]\Some folder\Yet another folder\Sub1\Printouts
```

What if I want to ignore only 1)? How can I specify a full path in *.gitignore*?

Thank you

Comment: Once a file is tracked by Git (added to a commit), it cannot be ignored anymore. `.gitignore` only applies to untracked files. Additionally, you want to use a forward slash `/` in your ignore file, not the Windows backslash``\``. Your last point is not correct (AFAIK)

Comment: I quickly verified your last claim in an empty repo, and I cannot confirm it. Nested files are not matched by a normal pattern, you need to use wildcards to match arbitrarily rooted/nested files

Comment: @knittl in the default *.gitignore* created by VisualStudio there is for example ``[Bb]in/``. This excludes from the repo every ``bin`` folder in the solution. See for example https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/gitignore (``logs/`` pattern).

Comment: There's a difference between `bin/` and `nested/bin/`. The former will match at all levels, the latter only at the root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Untrack* your whole directory, where you want to `.gitignore`:

```
git rm --cached -r Sub1/Printouts/
```

After that, all files and subfolders in `Sub1/Printouts` aren‘t tracked by `git`.

Now you can add this path to your `.gitignore` file, save it and then no further modifictions (add files, delete files, …) will be tracked by `git`:

```
Sub1/Printouts/
```